# Boost Rtree for Geographic Coordinates

Tags: boost, boost-geometry

I found some traces in the Boost Geometry library that there is some type of support for geographic coordinates (e.g. lat/lon).

Is there support for geographic coordinates in Boost's rtree implementation, and if so, how to use it? I cannot find anything in the documentation (might be a hint it ISN'T supported).

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the R-tree with geographic point/box type, e.g.:

```
namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

using point = bg::point<double, 2, bg::cs::geographic<bg::degree>>;
using rtree_p = bgi::rtree<point, bgi::rstar<4>>;

using box = bg::box<point>;
using rtree_bi = bgi::rtree<std::pair<box, size_t>, bgi::rstar<16>>;
```